# How do I find the coefficient of restitution COR when a sphere is hanging from a roof?

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

The diagram from below shows a sphere labeled $A$ and is moving with a horizontal speed of $v=4\sqrt{10}\,\frac{m}{s}$ over a frictionless table. After the collision the cable makes an angle of $53^{\circ}$ with the vertical and the sphere $A$ ends at rest. Find the $COR$ (coefficient of restitution) and the relationship between the masses.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\frac{1}{2},\, \frac{1}{2}\\
2.&\frac{1}{3},\, \frac{1}{6}\\
3.&\frac{1}{2},\, \frac{1}{3}\\
4.&\frac{1}{8},\, \frac{1}{2}\\
5.&\frac{1}{2},\, \frac{1}{6}\\
\end{array}$

When it mentions the COR for the collision I'm assuming that it is an inelastic collision. Therefore if treated as such then

$p_1=p_2$

$m_1 v_1=m_2 v_2$

$v_2=4\sqrt{10} \frac{m_1}{m_2}$

But that's how far I went. I'm stuck with this problem, can someone help me here?.

Comment: How did you get the last line of your working? It doesn't look right. If I understand your notation, $v_{1}$ is the velocity of $A$ immediately before the collision, and $v_{2}$ is the velocity of $B$ immediately after. If so, then $v_{1} = 4\sqrt{10}$ is given. Perhaps you mean $v_{2} = 4\sqrt{10} \frac{m_{1}}{m_{2}}$?

Comment: The angle $53^{\circ}$ is when sphere $B$ is at rest following the collision. That means it has gained some height, and thus gained some potential energy. Since it's at rest, it's lost some kinetic energy. You should try writing down some formulas for these energies.

Comment: @preferred_anon Sorry it was a typo. I'll try to write the formula as the conditions you mentioned. But at the beginning it will have kinetic energy and at the end it will be potential energy. Am I getting your idea right?

Comment: To get exactly what they have, you must use $\cos(53)=\frac 35$

Comment: @WW1 Perhaps can you offer some answer to guiding me on what should I do?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Indeed. Immediately after the collision, $B$ will have some kinetic energy (insert expression here); when $B$ is at the peak of its motion, it will have some gravitational potential energy (insert expression here). By conservation of energy, they are the same.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell I have noticed that a large number of questions previously asked by you don't have any accepted answers. I suggest you accept the most suitable answers that answer your questions. Not only does this reward the answerer for taking out time to clear your doubts, it also lets the community know that the question has received a satisfactory answer and doesn't need more answers.

Answer (score 1):

Initial momentum of $A$ is $4\sqrt{10}m_A$. This is equal to the momentum of $B$ after the collision. The kinetic energy of $B$ after the collision is then $p^{2}/2m_B = 80m_{A}^{2}\big/m_B$.

As has been noted, $B$ is raised by $2\text{m}$ by the collision, giving it a potential energy of $20m_{B} = \frac{1}{2}m_{B}v_{B}^{2}$. Note therefore that $v_{B} = \sqrt{40} = 2\sqrt{10}$.

Therefore $80m_{A}^{2} = 20m_{B}^{2}$, meaning $m_{A}/m_{B} = 1/2$.

The COR is then $$\frac{v_{B}}{v_A} = \frac{2\sqrt{10}}{4\sqrt{10}} = 1/2.$$